# nginx deny directory and files to be downloaded

Tags: nginx, deny

gurus. I have a problem and i dont know how to solve it. I am working with Git and Compass/SASS on some projects. Now i want to protect those directories. When i go **only** to the folder its all fine – i get what i expected a 403 forbidden.

```
location ~ /\.git {
        deny all;
}
```

But when i try use the full path to the config file from git the browser start to download it.
Same scenario with compass. There is a `config.rb` file within the folder which also starts to download it. How can i prevent this behaviour?

How can i deny downloading specific files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can deny specific file types using

```
location ~* \.(git|rb|inc|ht)$ {
    deny all;
}
```

Comment: Will this prevent files being downloaded?

Comment: How does this work if I am talking about a specific folder where these files are?

Comment: It worked for me!